# What does T designator means in PCB?

Tags: usb, usb-device, esd, router

I know Tdesignator normally means transformer, however i found t9 and t10 connected to a routers USB data line from ground. They could have been diodes for protection but diode's designator is D

[image: TPLink Archer C6 USB port]

I am new to electronics, i know i maybe asking stupid questions.

Comment: Certainly not transformers.  They are polarized with + connected to what looks like a ground plane...T for TVS?  You can write whatever you want on the silkscreen layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely a TVS diode, since it is a protection component on USB data lines.